# Ajax call with php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im using $.ajax in javascript. I need to get the response from php file. The code in javascript is -

```
var datavalues = {
                 a: 12,
                 b: 54
                 };


$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://localhost/example/test.php',
       data: datavalues,
       success: function(response)
       {
       console.log(response);
       $('#label').html(response);
       var responsevalue = response;
       }
       });
```

and the code in php file is -

```
$bt = rand(0, 99);
$bt = intval($bt);
echo $bt;
```

The issue is that it shows the value in the label but value is not coming fine in the responsevalue variable. I need integer value in the responsevalue variable.

Output of console.log(response);  statement is -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>68<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here 68 should be the value of responsevalue variable.

I hope you are not confused with the above code.

Comment: I see no element with an ID of `label` and you have 2 `<html>` tags. This makes no sense.

Comment: If you're using ajax and stuff like that it would be better for you to show us the actual code rather than a basic irrelevant  template, that is missing the relevant parts of your code. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: It seems you are confused. See the question again. I have edited it.

Comment: Can you put the code that make an AJAX request to your backend

Comment: I have edited again.

Comment: try to use $('#label').text(response);

Comment: In label it is fine. It is not coming fine in the responsevalue variable

Comment: @pareza If you `console.log(response)` you'll probably find that the response's *data* is in the subproperty `response.data`.

Comment: Ho are you responding within PHP to the ajax call? Where is your PHP response script?

Comment: response.data is not working too.

Comment: @Daniel see the php code above. It is returning the value with echo $bt; statement.

Comment: @pareza What's the output of `console.log(response)`, then?

Comment: @ceejayoz see above for the output of console.log(response);

Comment: @pareza If that's the response, your `http://localhost/example/test.php` does more than just `echo $bt;`. You need to stop it from outputting all that HTML around the value you want.

Comment: @ceejayoz   yes, you are right. The problem was in the test.php. There was the html code. I have removed it and it is coming fine now in the responsevalue variable. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given by @ceejayoz in the comments. For reference Im posting his answer here

"@pareza If that's the response, your http://localhost/example/test.php does more than just echo $bt;. You need to stop it from outputting all that HTML around the value you want."

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery param

```
var datavalues = {
                 a: 12,
                 b: 54
                 };


$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://localhost/example/test.php',
       data: $.param(datavalues),
       success: function(response)
       {
       console.log(response);
       $('#label').html(response);
       var responsevalue = response;
       }
       });
```

in PHP file echo $_POST['a'];

Comment: There is not any problem with post data. The issue is in the response.

Comment: @pareza, where is id label, i didn't see any where, instead try text()